# Reserve space using mmap, and map file later?

Tags: c, linux, posix, mmap

how would I go about mapping a file onto a reserved memory space? In my program, I'd like to:

- Reserve `size_t size` bytes using mmap at `addr` without a file mapping
- Upon specific call, map `fd` at a certain offset within the reserved mapping

I was thinking this could be accomplished by `munmap`'ing a region of the reserved space to map the file, but is there an easier way?

Here's some code to represent what i'm doing:

```
void* reserve(void* addr_hint, size_t map_size) {
    // stuff
    return (void *) mmap(addr_hint, page_multiple, PROT_NONE, map_flags, NULL, 0);
}

void* map(void* addr, int fd, size_t offset, size_t size) {
    // addr has already been reserved in the reserve function above
    // How do I proceed to mmap the file in a previously reserved memory space?
}
```

Comment: Don't need to `munmap`. Just `mmap` over the top of the existing reserved mapping. From the mmap man page: "MAP_FIXED: place the mapping at exactly that address.  If the memory region specified by addr and len overlaps pages of any existing mapping(s), then **the overlapped part of the existing mapping(s) will be discarded**."

Comment: You'll get more help if you describe what you tried that didn't work.